# Getting an error trying to load font with ExpoSDK

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to animate some fonts and this is what I have in the code:

```
   const labelStyle = {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      top: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [10, -10],
      }),
      fontSize: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [25, 14],
      }),
      color: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['black', 'gray'],
      }),
      fontFamily: this.animatedIsFocused.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['montserratBold', 'montserratRegular'],
      }),
    };
```

I call that like this:

`<Animated.Text style={labelStyle}>{labelText}</Animated.Text>`

The fonts I am using are loaded properly and I can use them everywhere in the app but not there in the animation:

```
  loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Font.loadAsync({
        ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
        montserratRegular: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
        montserratSemibold: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
        montserratBold: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
      }),
    ]);
  };
```

The error:

> Invariant Violation: invalid pattern montserratBold and montserratRegular

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to know too.

Comment: ...Icon.Ionicons.font,free
montserratRegular: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
        montserratSemibold: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
        montserratBold: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'), i did not get these lines. What does free mean?

Comment: I don't know react, but fast reading the Animated API docs, it sounds like when you pass strings to `interpolate.outputRange`, they will search for a number to replace with the current range. Makes sense, what do you expect `interpolate(0.5)` would output with your params? `monserratBolular`? And now, how do you want the interpolation between both font family be performed? A kind of morphing? You won't have it. The best you could do would be to convert your texts to SVG shapes, but you'd better go an other way entirely, like a simple fading.